# Using strtoul in C

Tags: c, strtol

In C, why does

`strtoul(argv[1])`

just doesn't work? It looks like more parameters are needed but I can't prevent how long the number will be.

Thanks!

p.s. (argv[1] is properly setted).

Comment: You need to find the documentation to `strtoul()` and read it before asking the question here. Stack Overflow is a wonderful community, but it's bordering on the impolite for you to not even attempt to read the documentation before asking us to spend our time doing that for you.

Comment: Hey, close voters: "should have used Google first" is not in any of the descriptions for reasons to close.

Comment: read it before posting (I'm not a moron) but I have no idea of what a "base" number is. Kind of math-noob here.

Comment: asking "Can you help me to understand the documentation about strtoul" would have been so different?

Comment: @Joseph - Yes, it would have. It would have implied that you tried and were having trouble. This question, as worded, implies that you didn't try and don't really understand C.

Comment: Well, I've tried short before. You're computation was wrong, then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you're calling it with the wrong number of arguments. Try

```
strtoul(argv[1], 0, 0);
```

Or if you want to enforce base-10 only:

```
strtoul(argv[1], 0, 10);
```

Be sure you included `<stdlib.h>` too!

Comment: +1 but using 0 for `NULL` kinda rubs me wrong...

Comment: I'll accept that it's personal preference, but I feel like using `NULL` gives one a false sense of safety when calling variadic functions or (uhg) functions lacking prototype. The implementation is allowed to define `NULL` as any null pointer constant, so `0`, `(void *)0`, or even `(1-1)` would be valid. Using `NULL` hides the non-portable assumption that `NULL` is defined as `(void *)0`, which leads to code that will break if that assumption is false. Using `0` catches the few cases (like variadic functions) where you really do need a cast and prompts you to fix them.

Comment: I think it's only allowed to be `0` or `(void *)0` but I'm on my iPhone so I can't check the standard. Wouldn't it be better to use `#define MYNULL ((void *)0)` then?

Comment: Note that with variadic functions, it's sometimes actually `(char *)0` you need. My preference is just to use the correct explicit cast when it's necessary, and otherwise use plain 0. But I can see how some people would dislike that, too. (By the way, plain 0 is also more C++-friendly, which some people may care about. I don't write worst-of-both-worlds code though. :-) )

Comment: @Chris: 6.3.2.3/3: "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a *null pointer constant*". 7.17/3: "The macros are `NULL` which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant...". `(1-1)` is an ICE with value 0. So is `0L` for that matter.

Answer (score 3):

The other parameters aren't for "how long the number will be". Read the manpage.

```
unsigned strtoul(char *s, char **endptr, int base);
```

`endptr` should be either `NULL` or the address of a `char *`. If it's not `NULL` the function sets the pointer to point to the first unused character in the string, so either a non-digit or the nul-termination.

`base` specifies what base the number is in. It can be between 2 and 52 (I believe). You probably want 10. As a special case, base 0 checks for a prefix of `0x` for hexidecimal and `0` for octal (and none for decimal) and converts accordingly.

Comment: +1 for explaining more than I did

Answer (score 1):

Try this (for decimal value):

```
strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 10)
```